# How can I redirect a domain to another domain that includes a path (using DNS)?

Tags: ssl, redirect, dns

- I have two domains with GoDaddy: **foo.com** and **bar.com**
- I want to redirect **foo.com** to **bar.com/foo**

I tried setting up *Domain Forwarding* from within the GoDaddy Dashboard and it did work, but not for **HTTPS** (which is the URL indexed within Google).

I checked with GoDaddy Support and received this response:

> That will not work because your domain does not have an SSL Certificate active and there is no way to activate an SSL Certificate on it with a forward.

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but here's an alternative approach I had in mind:

1. Set the **A record** of **foo.com** to the same IP address that **bar.com** is using
2. Within the website code of **bar.com**, check the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and redirect appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using plain **DNS** this is not possible, the reason for this is that DNS is a protocol different than **HTTP**.

Some providers offer "forwarding" options but behind the scenes, they point your domain to an HTTP server the one later does the redirect.

For example, using [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) this could be very easy to achieve, you need to setup up only one domain, let's say **foo.com** and then just create a page rule to redirect traffic to **bar.com/foo**, the rule could be something like:

```
*foo.com*
```

More info about the page rules can be found here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-